# "I like to see a movie" or "I like to see movies"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I learnt that you say "I like cats" and "I like movies" and that you don't say "I like a cat" or "I like a movie".  It makes sense to use the plural form when mentioning cats/movies in general and it is easy to understand.

However, how about this one?

- I like to see a movie.
- I like to see movies.

You never see two movies at a time, so "to like to see a movie" makes sense to me.  Having said that, it feels strange to like seeing only one movie.

Which sentence sounds more natural?

Comment: We say _**watch** movies_ more commonly.

Comment: That's irrelevant to the question and to see a movie is nothing wrong.  I've seen many argue that you "see" a movie in a theatre and "watch" a movie at home.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/do-you-watch-a-movie-or-see-a-movie

Comment: Regarding *see* vs *watch*, you asked which sentence sounds more natural. In American English, it’s most natural to say "I like to watch movies" if you’re speaking in general. I only ever hear *see* in the context of going to see a single movie in a theater. I don’t think I’ve ever heard anyone say "I like to see movies".

Comment: With emphasis on the *a*, that would mean it's the *only* cat or movie that you like. (Do you like cats?) I like *a* cat; my other one's kind of a jerk.

Answer (score 9):

In standard, and unremarkable English, "movies" would be normal.  Using "a movie" sounds like there is only one movie you are talking about.

If you specify a particular time like "after work on Friday", then limiting it to "one" makes sense

> I like to watch movies.  (general)

> I like to watch a movie on TV after work on Friday. (specific time)

And in some (socio-)dialects the form with "a" is more common.

The verb "watch" is better than "see", but both probably unnecessary (what else do you do with movies?)

Comment: This matches my intuitions. I think you'd also be more likely to use "a movie" when talking about going to the cinema, for the reason that it shows one movie at a time. But it's not a question of right or wrong.

Comment: (BrE) I'd say '*watching* movies' (well, 'films', but that's not my point) is more common, 'to watch' to me sounds either contrapositive to a suggestion that you *don't* like to, or like you're talking about a specific habit as in your second example - 'what do you do at the weekend?', 'I like to watch movies'.

Answer (score 3):

We usually specify the *object* of regular / repeated actions like this in the plural, as per [the usage chart below.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=likes%20to%20watch%20movies%2Clikes%20watching%20movies%2Clikes%20to%20watch%20a%20movie%2Clikes%20watching%20a%20movie&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

I did the chart for ***watch*** rather than ***see*** because the latter is far less common. OP is quite correct that *many argue that you "see" a movie in a theatre and "watch" a movie at home*, but the plurality of the object is the same regardless of the verb - which is *usually* an infinitive, but the continuous participle is also common.

[image]

Comment: Oh, you are still active. It's been 10 years!

Comment: Not *quite* 10 years on ELL! [Member for 9 years, 11 months.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers) Longer on EL**U**, which I'd joined some time before ELL was created.

Comment: Do you know StoneyB's real name? It would be great to be able to resume the contact.

Comment: I don't. But I think he is/was older than me, and he's not been here since late 2019, so perhaps old age and/or Covid is a factor in his non-appearance (I doubt "Monicagate" was the whole reason for him withdrawing, but who knows?).

Answer (score 0):

Good question! You would normally say “movies,” not “a movie.0

However, you can say something like

> I like to see a movie sometimes.

or

> I always like to watch a good movie!

which makes it clear, this is a habit of yours.